# JLink (flash load)/MDR32F1QI в Linux

Tags: linux, embedded

Недавно занялся программированием Российского микроконтроллера MDR32F1QI. Проблем со сборкой не говоря уже про сам контроллер не возникло. Однако, вот уже месяц как прошиваю контроллер из Windows c помошью Keil'a или програмки из поставки отладочной платы, а отлаживаю в Linux/Eclipse/JLink V8. Поскажите пожалуйста что мне написать в makefile'e для прошивки моего соотечественника (как угодно, хоть бы и вне makefile'a отдельной утилитой). Пробовал вот такую строку:

```
openocd -f target/1986ve1t.cfg -c init; reset halt; flash write_image erase $(RESULT).bin 0x00000000; reset run; shutdown
```

В ответ получаю следующее:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2015-09-02-10:42)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Error: Debug adapter does not support any transports? Check config file order.
Error: unable to select a session transport. Can't continue.
shutdown command invoked
reset: unknown terminal type halt
Terminal type?
```

Что за "terminal type" и что не нравится openocd? 
 Имя файла конфигурации openocd (1986ве1т.cfg) изменено (русские буквы в названиях файлов понятны не всем вспомогательным утилитам)

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше задавать в профильных форумах: сахара, электроникс итп, но учтите, публика там местами невменяемая.

Comment: Кто вам придумал такую строку? `unknown terminal type halt` выдаёт команда linux `reset` (см. `man reset`, ну не находит она терминала с именем halt). Точки с запятой в командной строке разделяют команды, поэтому так получилось.

Comment: Ну да не совсем эпик фейл, просто всю эту фигню нужно в кавычки запихнуть! по запарке даже такое бывает :( Утром попробую СПС! Это можно считать ответом, даже если не сработает!!! Бред в натуре какойто

Comment: @sercxjo, опубликуйте свой комментарий в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unknown terminal type halt` выдаёт команда linux `reset` (см. `man reset`, ну не находит она терминала с именем halt). Точки с запятой в командной строке разделяют команды shell, поэтому так получилось.

По-видимому всё после `-c` следует заключить в апострофы:

```
openocd -f target/1986ve1t.cfg -c 'init; reset halt; flash write_image erase $(RESULT).bin 0x00000000; reset run; shutdown'
```